# Do I remove STATIC & MEDIA roots when using AWS S3 storage with my Django project?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/s3-static-media-files-for-django/) to integrate **AWS S3 storage** to my django project. It involves adding a `~/project/app/aws/conf.py` file which includes:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_URL
STATIC_URL = S3_URL + 'static/'
```

Does this mean I should remove the `MEDIA_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` from `~/project/app/settings.py`? (and also `MEDIA_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT`?)

Answer (score 0):

yes you have to, as long as you are importing the conf.py in your settings.py